# Plastic damage from throttle body/carb cleaner

Tags: body-work, damage, plastic

I didn't realize carb cleaner was so damaging to plastic and unfortunately left marks on my car's plastic grill. Notice how the matte-ish black plastic looks shiny like water was spilled on it, but it is actually just "burns" from the carb cleaner.

Any ideas how I can repair this or at least make it look better?

[image: plastic grill]

Comment: Is this a crv mk2 front fascia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sanded out the damage for the most part. Some of it was surprisingly deep, but using fairly fine sandpaper (grits: 400 -> 600 -> 1000 -> 2000) seemed to work well.

I will try some plastic restorer if I'm still unsatisfied.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the grill, thoroughly clean it then spray it with plastic paint or even replace it. The damage caused by the solvent is most likely permanent.

Answer (score 4):

As you found out, the warnings on carburetor cleaner to avoid contact with plastic and paint are for a reason.

The black plastic looks faded, not necessarily an intended matte finish. Before spending a lot of money to have it painted or replace it, try washing it with warm soapy water and completely dry it. Then use a plastic restorer (like the wipe on kind found at auto parts store) to restore the plastic surface.

[image]
*(This picture is just for reference)*

Here is a helpful video on how to [restore and fix faded plastic trim on your car](https://youtu.be/MY_sxRrJO_E).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot remove the marks that it has created but yes you can hide them by using after market products like **dashboard polish** since dashboard is also  plastic or a [insta-shine](http://www.amazon.in/Motomax-Insta-Shine-Pack-5/dp/B01LQGXRPG) sponge.All you have to do is rub that sponge on the plastic surface that will give you a uniform texture

Answer (score 1):

After you use the super fine grit sandpaper or steel wool, try this: http://www.retr0bright.com/make.html

I know it sounds like it won't work, but it would lighten the darker spots to be more like the faded black part.

Try small sections first.